# ReactQuery: queryFn passed to useQuery is never run, happens only on Chrome

Tags: react-query

We make extensive use of ReactQuery on a fairly large React site, and it works well, but we've recently seen very strange behavior that happens only on Chrome, and only rarely.   For every `useQuery` we call, the `queryFn` we pass in is not being called, ever.  I verify this by beginning the `queryFn` function with logging, which never happens on Chrome.  `enabled` is hardcoded to `true`.  On Edge and Firefox, the logging happens, the code runs, the app is fine -- all the time.  I have not seen the problem once outside of Chrome.  I know `useQuery` is called because the key can be seen in reactQuery devtools.  Since the problem began on my machine, it happens with total consistency, but at this time only on this particular machine.  No one else on the team can duplicate it.  Previously a customer reported the same problem (again on Chrome only) and our various troubleshooting (clearing all localstorage, etc.) was not fruitful before the problem just stopped on its own.  It happens in regular and incognito mode, on my localhost server as well as our dev server, and it happens after clearing localstorage, restarting the local server, the browser, and the machine.  We're not persisting any reactQuery cache locally anyway.  Upgrading to reactQuery 4.24.9 did not make a difference.  No one else on the team hitting the same dev server with the same Chrome build (same version for Mac M1) is experiencing the problem.  If this sounds familiar to anyone, please chime in.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It does sound familiar. There is an issue in Chrome on mac (could be [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=678075)?) that `navigator.onLine` returns `false` even though there is actually network connection. I'm not sure if this has been fixed or not, but react-query uses `navigator.onLine` in the `OnlineManager` to check if network connection exists. If there is no network, the `queryFn` is not run in the default `networkMode: 'online'`.

You can check if that is the case if the `fetchStatus` returned from `useQuery` shows `'paused'`. You should also be able to see this in the react-query-devtools.

You can change the `networkMode` to something else ([see the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/network-mode)). I've also read reports that just turning wifi on and off fixes it. It's annoying, but to my knowledge, there is no better way to determine if you have network connection or not. You can of course provide your own event listener to the onlineManager via [onlineManager.setEventListener](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/onlineManager#onlinemanagerseteventlistener). If you have a different way to detect online / offline, you can plug this in there.

/update:

Starting with `@tanstack/react-query` v5, we'll treat the browser as always being online initially until we get an `offline` event and will thus no longer listen to `navigator.onLine` due to all the false positives. This is a tradeoff because it might make the experience worse when you are actually offline, but it seems like the lesser evil.

Comment: You just saved my life, was going crazy trying to figure out why my app worked on windows but not on mac

Comment: I spent so many hours debugging this today. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thank you! I spent so much time to this...

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me. I was building a side project and things were working fine about 8 hours ago. Now all my queries show the status as paused in the react-query devtools panel.

I am running this on brave on a mac. Although the issue was solved by turning the wifi off and back on, but this is slightly annoying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).